# How to wait for asynchronous part in function in swift?

Tags: swift, asynchronous

I have a function that must return a calculated value, the problem is that the value returned is the value initialized at the beginning of the function. A part of the function is asynchronous, so this part has no time to be executed before the function returns the value.

I don't know how to wait for the asynchronous part of the code.

So the print in the asynchronous part of the code returns the right value, but the print just before the return, return a value calculated with the initialized value of the variable placeMarkCoordinates variable that has not had time to be modified.

```
func getDistance(placeMarkLocation: MKLocalSearchCompletion, currentLocation: CLLocation) -> String {
  let searchRequest = MKLocalSearch.Request(completion: placeMarkLocation)
  let search = MKLocalSearch(request: searchRequest)
  var placeMarkCoordinates: CLLocation = CLLocation(latitude: 0, longitude: 0)
    
  // Asynchronous part:
  search.start { (response, error) in
    guard let coordinate = response?.mapItems[0].placemark.coordinate else {
      return
    }

    placeMarkCoordinates = CLLocation(latitude: coordinate.latitude, longitude: coordinate.longitude)
    print(currentLocation.distance(from: placeMarkCoordinates))
  }
    
  print(currentLocation.distance(from: placeMarkCoordinates))
  return "\(currentLocation.distance(from: placeMarkCoordinates).getDistanceString)"
}
```

Comment: You don't wait. You cannot return a value that is supplied asynchronously, because you return before the value is supplied; that is what asynchronous means.

Comment: Please read http://www.programmingios.net/what-asynchronous-means/ then http://www.programmingios.net/you-cant-use-a-value-after-it-has-been-set-by-asyncronous-code/ then http://www.programmingios.net/returning-a-value-from-asynchronous-code/

Answer (score 2):

You should not use a return method. Instead, use a closure in your getDistance method.

Declare method like so:

```
func getDistance(placeMarkLocation: MKLocalSearchCompletion, currentLocation: CLLocation, completion: @escaping (String) -> ()) {
    // Within your async block, do:
    completion(yourReturnStringValue)

    // This way, no value leaves the method before the async process is finished
}
```

Call method like so:

```
getDistance(placeMarkLocationValue, currentLocationValue) { returnStringValue in
    // Your returnStringValue can be used here
}
```

Comment: Also note, the completion should be the last code that gets called in the async block, put print statements BEFORE it.

Comment: Thank you, I wonder how I could use this in a swiftui context, in a Text() 

Comment: Sorry, can’t help you there. Shouldn’t be too hard though

Comment: Your question tag is Swift, not SwiftUI. Maybe you should clarify your question if my answer is not correct in your case.

Comment: @Guillaume, did you make it work somehow?

Comment: Yes: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68763177/how-to-use-completionhandler-response-in-swiftui/68763613#68763613 