# How to use completionHandler response in swiftui?

Tags: swiftui, completionhandler

In a swiftui application, I retrieve addresses based on a search bar. For each address, I want to retrieve the distance between the user's location and the address. So I created a function (which returns a string) that I call directly in a text component of swiftui. But the answer comes from a completionHandler, and I don't know how to get this kind of answer in a text().

Function that return distance in string:

```
func getDistance(placeMarkLocation: MKLocalSearchCompletion, currentLocation: CLLocation, completionHandler: @escaping (String) -> ()) {
  let searchRequest = MKLocalSearch.Request(completion: placeMarkLocation)
  let search = MKLocalSearch(request: searchRequest)
  var placeMarkCoordinates: CLLocation = CLLocation(latitude: 0, longitude: 0)
        
  search.start { (response, error) in
    guard let coordinate = response?.mapItems[0].placemark.coordinate else {
      return
    }

    placeMarkCoordinates = CLLocation(latitude: coordinate.latitude, longitude: coordinate.longitude)
      
    completionHandler("\(currentLocation.distance(from: placeMarkCoordinates).getDistanceString)")
  }
}
```

```
ForEach(locationSearchService.searchResults.indices, id: \.self) { index in
  HStack(spacing: 5) {
    VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 2) {
      TextWithAttributedString(attributedString: self.highlightedText(
        text: locationSearchService.searchResults[index].title,
        inRanges: locationSearchService.searchResults[index].titleHighlightRanges,
        size: 20.0
      ) as! NSMutableAttributedString, dynamicHeight: $height)
        .frame(minHeight: height)
        .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)                                   
      }
      .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: geometry.size.width)
      .padding(.leading, 15)
      .padding(.top, 10)
      .padding(.bottom, index + 1 == locationSearchService.searchResults.count ? 20 : 10)

      Spacer()
      
      // No work          
      Text("\(self.getDistance(placeMarkLocation: locationSearchService.searchResults[index], currentLocation: CLLocation(latitude: 47.2102877, longitude: -1.5692436)) { value in value })")
        .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
        .padding(.trailing, 15)
        .padding(.top, index == 0 ? 20 : 10)
        .padding(.bottom, index + 1 == locationSearchService.searchResults.count ? 20 : 10)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Your problem is going to be a little more complicated because of the `ForEach`, meaning you have multiple calls to `getDistance`. Basically, you'll want to call `getDistance` for each of the items and store them somewhere -- maybe a `Dictionary` keyed by the location ID. Then, in your `ForEach`, you would only display that `Text` if there's a value in the `Dictionary` (ie, `getDistance` has completed and there's a value to show).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a subview that would take a search result (`locationSearchService.searchResults[index]`) as a parameter. And whose purpose would be to display the calculated distance.
The function that calculates the distance (`getDistance`) could be executed when this (each) subview appears (`onAppear`).
And the completion handler would update the state of this subview.

```
struct DistanceView: View {
    @State private var distance: String?
    let placeMarkLocation: MKLocalSearchCompletion
    var body: some View {
        Text(distance ?? "getting distance")
            .onAppear {
                getDistance(placeMarkLocation: placeMarkLocation, currentLocation: CLLocation(latitude: 47.2, longitude: -1.5)) { value in
                    distance = value
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: I had not thought of this approach, thanks, it work like a charm!